# MySQL update datetime field

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following query that is executing successfully, but it is NOT updating the record. `Departure_Date2` and `Arrival_Date2` are datetime fields.  I can't for the life of me figure out why? I've tried with a dash and a forwardslash and still nothing.

```
UPDATE table SET 
Departure_Date2 =  '22/Nov/15 17:37',
Arrival_Date2 =  '22/Nov/15 19:20' 
WHERE PK =131500
```

Comment: please let me know field type for both column..

Comment: I hope table is generic name and not real SQL instruction. What's the name of your table?

Comment: its generic table name is travel

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A datetime data type has the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

For example, 3:30 in the afternoon on December 30th, 1973 would be stored as 1973-12-30 15:30:00.

Comment: For some reason the / was not correct...I tried it again with a dash and it worked, thanks!

Comment: `UPDATE `meter_to_sim_mapping` mp UPDATE mp.`mapped_at` = "2018-03-20 14:51:40" WHERE 1` not updating

Answer (score 1):

i have tried with timestamp datatype for column :

```
UPDATE wpcads_paypal SET Departure_Date2 =  '22/Nov/15 17:37',
Arrival_Date2 =  '22/Nov/15 19:20'
```

working well..

Comment: Highly implausible